# Where can I ask questions on cloud computing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, serverfault

I need to ask some questions on cloud computing. I think **Server Fault** may be perfect place for such questions, but are there any specific Stack Exchange sites where can I ask questions on cloud computing?

Comment: As usual, my favorite answer applies: *It depends*. What is your question?

Comment: Since the question could easily be answered by googling or doing a search right here I assume this is an opinion question.  My opinion would be that stackoverflow is the place for cloud computing.

Answer (score 31):

These are your likely options:

- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) - related to cloud computing platforms that you might manage or configure your self
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - related to programming against a cloud computing platform or an API etc
- [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) - needing help with a cloud based app from a user's perspective, not a developer's
- [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) - running a cloud based app on a third party server

But really, without more context it is hard to tell

Comment: `Server Fault` and `Pro Webmasters` are the ones for me!

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, without more context as to what you're asking about, it's hard to tell. You might also have some luck, if your questions are about using Cloud Computing for HPC or other scientific computing, over at the shiny new Computational Science beta site: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

While not live, there is a site proposal in the "Definition" stage for [Practical cloud computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).  With additional test questions, and clarification about what type of cloud computing question you are asking, this site may fit your needs if it enters private/public beta.

Comment: That proposal has been closed