# Is there a stack site for Cloud computing (in general)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

At the risk of this being a duplicate - and I have seen [this question - Where can I ask questions on cloud computing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing) - I'm struggling to identify the right stack to post a question on.

Unlike in the linked question, I can provide more context.  My question is networking across different resources in MS Azure.  Server Fault is not the right forum, as my question is not about servers at all. Network Engineering also doesn't seem like the right place, as my question is about how to correctly configure my resources in Azure.

I have seen various questions on Stack Overflow regarding Azure configurations, which have had various degree of success in getting an answer.  I tried [posting there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291450/allow-access-to-storage-account-from-old-cloud-service-classic-in-azure) - but the question is quite specific; it's not at all about programming, there is no software involved at all.

So, any suggestions on the right stack to post these questions on would be very helpful.

Comment: Serverfault isn't 'just' for servers, its for system administration. We also have a devops site that might work?

Comment: *[DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour)*

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can consult the FAQ: ["Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/282094), other times the number of questions or the flavor of the answer you require can be used to guide your choice.

Microsoft [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) questions can be asked on:

- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 3880 questions [On-topic help](https://serverfault.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 589 questions [On-topic help](https://superuser.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 204 questions [On-topic help](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 109 questions [On-topic help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 79 questions [On-topic help](https://askubuntu.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 59 questions [On-topic help](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) - 7 questions [On-topic help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)