# Minor edits on meta site

Tags: discussion, edits

Early today I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383513/is-there-stack-site-for-cloud-computing-in-general). Very shortly afterwards, the question was edited, with a large number of minor, totally unneeded edits made:

[image]

None of them make the question any easier to understand or read, arguably, some make it more difficult. The user is not new, with over 6K rep on the meta site. I rolled back these edits and left a comment for the editor to avoid making these edits. However this left me thinking about what to do with such edits? Flagging the question to moderators seems too excessive to me.

**UPDATE:** within minutes of me rolling back those edits, another 6.9K rep user made more minor edits:

[image]

What should I do about it?

Comment: Edited mostly for irony. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask - why do you think being wrong is OK and being right is not OK? Because you repeatedly used the wrong terms there: "StackOverflow" and "ServerFault" are *not* the correct names of the sites "Stack Overflow" and "Server Fault". It's not really just that you've repeatedly made the same mistake - you've publicly complained over the well-intended corrections.

Comment: `some make it more difficult` -> could you explain which changes made your question harder to read or understand? While generally I agree that edits _too minor_ can be a nuisance, I don't think there's necessarily anything bad with minor cleanup that includes very obvious corrections and maybe other things that wouldn't have been crucial on their own, so long as none of the changes actually change the meaning.

Comment: Also, getting into edit wars with people who are correcting terms like `StackOverflow` (incorrect) to `Stack Overflow` (correct) is probably not the path you want to go down. You're going to get the question flagged, locked, and maybe worse.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36999/how-should-disputes-be-handled-on-stack-overflow) might be worthwhile reads.

Comment: @AaronBertrand is it ironic that the second link uses `Stackoverflow`?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace In the titles of questions from 14 years ago? Maybe. I think the space became a significant issue more recently, but not significant enough to demand a total history rewrite. Especially in cases like this, which copied the titles _at the time_ rather than use the system to generate the title _now_.  :-)

Comment: @ElementsInSpace That instance has been corrected, but I'm sure many remain.

Answer (score 12):

> What should I do about it?

Nothing. Neither of those edits made your post worse, and they definitely improved things. You may consider these improvements minor, but if your post only has minor errors (like missing 'a' in the title, a missing question mark, a missing whitespace in the names for both Server Fault and Stack Overflow), you shouldn't be expecting people to be making major edits just to also be able to fix the minor stuff.